# What is the idea of extending interface to create repository in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is [is said here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour), that to add one single method to repository, one need to create 3 (three) classes or interfaces.

Is this true and what is the purpose of such mambo-yambo? Is the only benefit of interface extending is the ability to create methods by naming convention? Does this benefit really overweights the loss of ability to create own methods?

**UPDATE**

Why can't I do `implements CrudRepository`?

I tried to use `implements`,

```
// does not work
//public abstract class CustomerRepository implements CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
//
//    abstract List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
//}

// works
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

but it does not work with error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type 
[hello.CustomerRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [hello.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hello.CustomerRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: This is a messy question. Your rep indicates that you should know better ;) How about removing everything up to the update -- because you know that it's too broad a question for us to tackle? And, then, we can have a go at explaining spring data jpa to you -- which basically auto-generates implementations at runtime.

Comment: I am relatively new to Spring. Each time I read their dox I have strong mambo-yambo feeling :)

Comment: Spring is the simplest way to do almost anything. If you get a wobbly stomach over that, try reading the JEE docs (hint -- they're totally the wrong answer ;).

Comment: I know that. But this doesn't change my criticism :(

Answer (score 3):

If you want only crud and pagination operations, Spring already provides implementations for these operations though they are interfaces. You dont have to implement any of these. You just have to extend the crud and if needed pagination interface. Spring will scan for the repository interfaces and provide implementation for crud, pagination operations, annotated interface methods with query annotation and to methods if you abide rules given by Spring data like findByLastname().

Sometimes there are cases when there is a need to give your own implementation. In such cases, you need to follow as per documentation to give your own implementation.

Spring data searches for interfaces extending Repository interface. And not abstract classes.

Link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances

Text from that link

> In the preceding example, **Spring is instructed to scan com.acme.repositories and all its sub-packages for interfaces extending Repository or one of its sub-interfaces**. For each interface found, the infrastructure registers the persistence technology-specific FactoryBean to create the appropriate proxies that handle invocations of the query methods. Each bean is registered under a bean name that is derived from the interface name, so an interface of UserRepository would be registered under userRepository. The base-package attribute allows wildcards, so that you can define a pattern of scanned packages.

**Javadoc of Repository interface:**

> org.springframework.data.repository.Repository   
>   Central repository marker interface. Captures the domain type to manage as well as the domain type's id type. General purpose is to hold type information as well as being able to discover interfaces that extend this one during classpath scanning for easy Spring bean creation.
>   Domain repositories extending this interface can selectively expose CRUD methods by simply declaring methods of the same signature as those declared in CrudRepository.